# Find specific String, Copy and Rename

Tags: python, indexing

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to write a script to copy .jpgs from one destination to another. That part works, however I'm trying to exclude certain thumbnails that contains certain strings that ends with "big", "iphone" and "wbig". When I run it, I get a "slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method". My other question is, endswidth only takes in three parameters...is there another method I can use to exclude more?

```
import os, shutil, re

def copy_files_over(src, dest):
src_files = os.listdir(src)
for file_name in src_files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)   
    full_destination=os.path.join(dest,file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name) and  )and not file_name.endswith('big', 'iphone' 'wbig')):
        while os.path.exists(full_destination):
            full_destination += ".duplicate"
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, full_destination)

dest = 'C:/image_out'
src= 'C:/image_in'

copy_files_over(src, dest) # copy files

print "test complete";
```

Next, I want to rename a jpg once it's moved over...I.E "My_Picture" would be renamed to "My_Picture_Renamed". I haven't started on that code yet, but any fingers in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change this bit (which doesn't work correctly)

```
file_name.endswith('big', 'iphone' 'wbig'))
```

to this and it will work as you requested

```
any(file_name.endswith(x) for x in ('big', 'iphone', 'wbig'))
```

following comment: Look for the string in any part of the word:

```
any(x in file_name for x in ('big', 'iphone', 'wbig'))
```

Comment: Thanks Andy...for some reason, images containing those strings are still printing. All of them include the string "thumbnail" in the file name...is there a way to exclude all files containing the string "thumbnail"? The file does not end in "thumbnail" so i don't think the endswidth type would work